# Getting JSON feed results: Origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Tags: javascript, json, rss

I'm trying to get some data from a web feed. However, I'm getting an Access-Control-Allow-Origin error that is preventing me from getting the necessary feed objects. My feed is hosted at a different address than my online app. So let's say my feed is hosted at: myfeedsaddress.com and my app is hosted at: myowndomainadd.com. The code I use to grab the data from the feed is:

```
        var jxhr = $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
            console.log("success!!");
                results = []
            var obj = $.parseJSON(data);
            $.each(obj, function(i,item){
            if (item.id == clss) {
                results.append(item.id);    
            }
            });
        });
```

The error I get when running this code is:

> OPTIONS myfeedaddress.com Origin myowndomain.com is not allowed by
>   Access-Control-Allow-Origin. XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   myfeedadress.com. Origin myowndomain.com is not allowed by
>   Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

Is there any way to get around this error? NOTE: I cannot modify the feed, I can only modify myowndomain.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a cross domain restriction imposed by the browser.It won't let you make ajax requests to a site that is hosted under a different domain. Default browsers settings prevent this in most cases.

One potential workaround is to create a proxy page hosted under myowndomain.com that makes a request to the other domain on the server. You can then return that via ajax by requesting the proxy page from your getJSON script.